# Trace definition of module during Rails boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a weird issue where I have a module that is being mysteriously defined at some point during the boot process of my Rails app, and I can't figure out where. The name of the module is `Cause`.

I've tried:

- grepping the project directory for `class Cause` or `module Cause` with no results
- `pry`ed at every step of `config/application.rb` and checked with `Object.const_get('Cause')`... throughout all of that file it was undefined (returned a `NameError: uninitialized constant Cause` – which is good)
- `pry`ed at my first initializer, and it ***was*** defined there.
- using [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) to set a breakpoint that I would hope would halt execution at the moment `Cause` was being defined, but it didn't like the following expression: `break if (Object.const_get('Cause') rescue false)`

Anyone have any debugging strategies I haven't tried? It would be awesome to have Rails halt in a pry session right at the moment it's defined, but I can't figure out how to make that happen. Also, what's inbetween the evaluation of `config/application.rb` and `config/initializers/*` in the boot process? [The Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) on the subject doesn't seem to mention the `config/initializers` directory...

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It may be coming from one of the gems you have installed. Can you show us a list of the gems you have in your Gemfile?

Comment: @infused Added to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the [tracepoint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/TracePoint.html) api.

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:class) do |tp|
  puts "#{tp.self} defined at #{tp.path}:#{tp.lineno}"
end

trace.enable
```

will produce output as each class is defined, with a file location. Prior to ruby 2.0 you can use `set_trace_func` which has broadly the same functionality but with a more awkward api.

This won't produce a very useful answer if the class is defined inside a call to `eval` or similar, but it looks like you should still be able to call `caller` to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what it was using `git bisect` and going back months in my code base... turns out the offender is [`gem 'cells'`](https://github.com/apotonick/cells). Spelunking in the cells codebase now to identify the bug and issue a PR to fix it...

Still, it would've been nice to have some way to halt execution when a module is defined... would've saved me the time of a massive bisect.